# Populating search results with meta data in Amazon CloudSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

Unfortunately, Amazon CloudSearch [does not support nested JSON](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=405879&#405879), meaning that the below document structure is not valid.

```
[{
    "type": "add",
    "id": 1,
    "fields": {
        "company_name": "My Company",
        "services": [
            {
                "id": 123,
                "name": "Construction",
                "logo": "logo1.png"
            },
            {
                "id": 456,
                "name": "Programming",
                "logo": "logo2.png"
            }
        ]
  }
}]
```

Basically I cannot nest an array of objects under the `services` key. In this particular scenario, only the nested `name` field has to be searchable, so what I could do is the following:

```
[{
    "type": "add",
    "id": 1,
    "fields": {
        "company_name": "My Company",
        "services": [ "Construction", "Programming" ]
  }
}]
```

The above JSON is valid, and I can still search for the service names. However, now I have lost some meta data about my services that I need when displaying the search results. Is there any way in which I can add the meta data to the document in Amazon CloudSearch and have it returned with my search results, such that I can use it when displaying the results?

Or do I have to fetch this additional meta data from my database afterwards to populate the search results with the additional data required to display the results? This does not seem feasible because it complicates my code much more than if I could fetch this data straight from CloudSearch. This would also impact the performance of the search, even though I could use caching - but I kind of want to avoid that if possible, because I don't need it for anything else right now.

So my questions are:

1. Can I somehow add the meta data for services to the CloudSearch documents and have it returned with my search results?
2. If not, should I then extract this data from my data store upon receiving the search results from CloudSearch?
3. Do you have any other solutions or ideas? Are there any best practices with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: My understanding is that you shouldn't be using CloudSearch as a datastore. It should return minimal information (ideally just IDs), which you then use to retrieve data. There is a little blurb about it here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/retrieving-data.html

Comment: @alexroussos Yes, I was considering to fetch additional data from my data store after retrieving the search results. Some of the data is a bit "expensive" to compute performance wise, so I was thinking about returning the fields that I am searching in CloudSearch (because they are there anyways), and then populating the results with additional data that is fetched from my data store afterwards. I guess there is no need to look _everything_ up based on IDs when I can return most of the data from directly CloudSearch. Do you have any comments on this? Thank you very much for your comment!

Comment: That seems reasonable, just bear in mind that you may be violating the Single Source of Truth Principle and that CloudSearch's values may not always match what you have in your datastore (I'm assuming this data is stored in both places). You could encounter some weird scenarios where stale data is returned from CloudSearch (eg if an SDF submission failed). But if you're cool with that risk then give it a try. Good luck!

Comment: Another idea (terrible hack) regarding your original goal would be to store the JSON rep of your object in a returnable text field. You would aggregate the data into arrays (transform "services" into "service_names" and "service_ids") like you did in your second snippet to make it searchable, but then add a new return field that would just hold the JSON you want to return in results (the JSON rep of "services"). I don't see a limit on field value length (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/limits.html) but I'm sure there is one... like I said, extremely hacky.

Comment: @alexroussos Good points. You are right that the latter approach seems hacky, and I will refrain from doing that, but you are right that it would indeed be a possibility. Thank you very much for your input, I appreciate it!

Comment: @alexroussos If you can write an answer with what you wrote in the comments, then I will accept it. Thanks again.